# iOS - Use/pass gesture recognizer for multiple Tableviews or Collectionviews in a View(Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uigesturerecognizer, swift4

I've got 2 (circular) UICollectionviews in my view, both are functioning but I want to use 1 swipe gesture for both views so when I swipe on the top collectionview, the bottom view should also swipe with the same speed and vice-versa. What would be the best way to achieve this?

This is my UIViewController:
[image: 2 Circular collectionviews]

both collectionviews should scroll whenever I scroll anywhere on this UIViewController. Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `scrollView delegate` of your collectionView's `scrollView`. `UICollectionView` is a subclass of `UIScrollView`. 
Use `scrollViewDidScroll` method. In that method you can for example see `contentOffset` of one `UICollectionView` and then set `contentOffset` to the other `collectionView's scrollView` to that value.

Comment: ScrollViewDidScroll will only be called when the scrolling is done, I need a func that's called constantly while scrolling to keep it moving smooth at the same time. Also I can not override the scrollView or it's delegate of my UICollectionview :(

Comment: Did you ever find an answer that works for you? Thanks!